# Vb.net crystal report not displaying the items

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, crystal-reports

I am trying to display all of the purchases in an inventory system but it is not displaying in my crystal report PS: this my first time using Crystal Report
 here's my code:

```
    Dim show As String = String.Empty
        show &= "select * from purchase_report "
        show &= "where buildnumber=@build"

        Using conn As New SqlConnection("Server=WIN10;database=purchase_stock;user=admin_report;password=54321")
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand
                With cmd
                    .Connection = conn
                    .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    .CommandText = show
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@build", report.Text)
                End With

                Try
                    conn.Open()

                    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                    Dim ds As New DataSet
                    da.Fill(ds)

                    If ds.Tables.Count > 0 Then
                        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = ds.Tables.Count
                    End If
                    conn.Close()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox(ex.Message)
                End Try
            End Using
        End Using


    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

Change it as per your needs

```
Friend Function ViewReport(ByVal sReportName As String, _
    Optional ByVal sSelectionFormula As String = "", _
    Optional ByVal param As String = "") As Boolean

    'Declaring variables
    Dim intCounter As Integer
    Dim intCounter1 As Integer

    'Crystal Report's report document object
    Dim objReport As New _
        CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument 

    'object of table Log on info of Crystal report
    Dim ConInfo As New CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo

    'Parameter value object of crystal report 
    ' parameters used for adding the value to the parameter.
    Dim paraValue As New CrystalDecisions.Shared.ParameterDiscreteValue

    'Current parameter value object(collection) of crystal report parameters.
    Dim currValue As CrystalDecisions.Shared.ParameterValues

    'Subreport object of crystal report.
    Dim mySubReportObject As _
        CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.SubreportObject

    'Sub report document of crystal report.
    Dim mySubRepDoc As New _
        CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument

    Dim strParValPair() As String
    Dim strVal() As String
    Dim index As Integer

    Try

        'Load the report
        objReport.Load(sReportName)

        'Check if there are parameters or not in report.
        intCounter = objReport.DataDefinition.ParameterFields.Count

        'As parameter fields collection also picks the selection 
        ' formula which is not the parameter
        ' so if total parameter count is 1 then we check whether 
        ' its a parameter or selection formula.

        If intCounter = 1 Then
            If InStr(objReport.DataDefinition.ParameterFields(_
                0).ParameterFieldName, ".", CompareMethod.Text) > 0 Then
                intCounter = 0
            End If    
        End If

        'If there are parameters in report and 
        'user has passed them then split the 
        'parameter string and Apply the values 
        'to their concurrent parameters.

        If intCounter > 0 And Trim(param) <> "" Then
            strParValPair = param.Split("&")

            For index = 0 To UBound(strParValPair)
            If InStr(strParValPair(index), "=") > 0 Then
                strVal = strParValPair(index).Split("=")
                paraValue.Value = strVal(1)
                currValue = _ 
                    objReport.DataDefinition.ParameterFields(_
                    strVal(0)).CurrentValues
                currValue.Add(paraValue)
                objReport.DataDefinition.ParameterFields(_
                    strVal(0)).ApplyCurrentValues(currValue)
            End If
        Next
    End If

    'Set the connection information to ConInfo 
    'object so that we can apply the 
    'connection information on each table in the report
    ConInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = <User Name>
    ConInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = <Password>
    ConInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = <Server Name>
    ConInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = <Database Name>

    For intCounter = 0 To objReport.Database.Tables.Count - 1
        objReport.Database.Tables(intCounter).ApplyLogOnInfo(ConInfo)
    Next

    ' Loop through each section of the report then look 
    ' through each object in the section
    ' if the object is a subreport, then apply login info 
    ' on each table of that subreport

        For index = 0 To objReport.ReportDefinition.Sections.Count - 1
            For intCounter = 0 To _
                objReport.ReportDefinition.Sections(_
                index).ReportObjects.Count - 1
            With objReport.ReportDefinition.Sections(index)
                If .ReportObjects(intCounter).Kind = _
                CrystalDecisions.Shared.ReportObjectKind.SubreportObject Then
                    mySubReportObject = CType(.ReportObjects(intCounter), _
                      CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.SubreportObject)
                    mySubRepDoc = _ 
             mySubReportObject.OpenSubreport(mySubReportObject.SubreportName)
                 For intCounter1 = 0 To mySubRepDoc.Database.Tables.Count - 1
                       mySubRepDoc.Database.Tables(_
                           intCounter1).ApplyLogOnInfo(_
                           ConInfo)sp;
                       mySubRepDoc.Database.Tables(_
                           intCounter1).ApplyLogOnInfo(ConInfo)
                 Next
                 End If
             End With
         Next
     Next
    'If there is a selection formula passed to this function then use that
    If sSelectionFormula.Length > 0 Then
        objReport.RecordSelectionFormula = sSelectionFormula
    End If
    'Re setting control 
    rptViewer.ReportSource = Nothing

    'Set the current report object to report.
    rptViewer.ReportSource = objReport

    'Show the report
    rptViewer.Show()
        Return True
    Catch ex As System.Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Function
```